# Django Really Simple Aggregation (or Group By)

Tags: sql, django, group-by, aggregation

Imagine I just want to know the number of users with the same **first_name** in Django's *auth app*.
I know how to do this really easy in SQL:

```
SELECT first_name, COUNT(1) as num_users 
  FROM auth_user 
  GROUP BY first_name
  ORDER BY num_users DESC;
```

And I also know how to get the desired output in Django (e.g. like going through all the users, get their email and do a *filter* and *count*, for instance).

**Isn't there a simpler way to do this via Django's ORM?** I can accomplish it if I'm aggregating with a foreign key but not with one of the table fields. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I blogged about [this very issue](http://blog.roseman.org.uk/2010/05/10/django-aggregation-and-simple-group/) a couple of years ago. Contrary to the other answers, it's perfectly possible in Django, with no need for raw SQL.

Comment: Never knew about this. Very useful.

Comment: Thank you @daniel-roseman :) Just like you say in the blog it is well documented and I've read it lot's of times but didn't get it :/ And I think you're right when you say "because of the (probably correct) desire not to express things in terms of SQL, it's not that easy to find"

Answer (score 1):

Django's [annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) allow you to attach some basic calculations to each object in your queryset (or aggregations across the entire queryset) but you can't filter those annotations (i.e. in your case, you only want to count thoseusers who share your name)

Django also has [`F() objects`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model) which allow you to use a fields value within a query. Ideally you could use these in conjunction with annotations to filter the objects you are annotation, [but that's not currently possible (there's a fix on the way)](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14030)

So, an easy solution is to perform the annotation manually:

```
users = User.objects.all().extra(select={
    'same_name_count' : """
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM auth_user
    WHERE auth_user.first_name = user.first_name
    """
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/

```
from django.db.models import Count
auth_user.objects.annotate(num_users=Count('first_name'))
```

For more complex queries you can use plain SQL but try to avoid it.

**UPD** Code fixed. Thanks Timmy O'Mahony for mention!

Comment: this will just count and return all the users that have a first_name set.